# Listening error on port 80 when nothing else is using it

Tags: command-line, networking, 18.04, server, webserver

I'm migrating my webserver from my Windows laptop over to another computer running Ubuntu 18.04 server. The program I'm using is Abyss Web Server (although it doesn't seem to be an issue with the program, it seems more likely to be something to do with Ubuntu).

I can run this Web Server fine, if it's on a different port (like port 8000, 8080, etc), but when I try using port 80, I get this error:

```
-- Default host on port 80 has a listening problem (Local URL http://127.0.0.1)

Console local URL: http://127.0.0.1:9999
```

Since it can listen on any other port I specify, this has to be an Ubuntu issue.

Before, I noticed that Apache2 was automatically enabled and using port 80, so I disabled it from starting up automatically, then disabled the service. I then rebooted the computer.

Upon starting it up again, I had the exact same problem. I used the `sudo lsof` command, and according to that, nothing was using it (this is just a snippet, obviously, but as you can see, nothing's on 80):

```
kswapd0     40                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/40/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
kswapd0     40                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/40/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
kworker/u   41                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/41/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
kworker/u   41                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/41/root (readlink: Permission denied)
kworker/u   41                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/41/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
kworker/u   41                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/41/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
ecryptfs-   42                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/42/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
ecryptfs-   42                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/42/root (readlink: Permission denied)
ecryptfs-   42                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/42/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
ecryptfs-   42                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/42/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
kthrotld    84                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/84/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
kthrotld    84                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/84/root (readlink: Permission denied)
kthrotld    84                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/84/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
kthrotld    84                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/84/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
acpi_ther   85                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/85/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
acpi_ther   85                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/85/root (readlink: Permission denied)
acpi_ther   85                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/85/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
acpi_ther   85                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/85/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
kworker/u   86                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/86/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
kworker/u   86                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/86/root (readlink: Permission denied)
kworker/u   86                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/86/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
kworker/u   86                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/86/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
ipv6_addr   90                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/90/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
ipv6_addr   90                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/90/root (readlink: Permission denied)
ipv6_addr   90                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/90/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
ipv6_addr   90                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/90/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
kstrp       99                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/99/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
kstrp       99                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/99/root (readlink: Permission denied)
kstrp       99                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/99/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
kstrp       99                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/99/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
charger_m  116                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/116/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
charger_m  116                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/116/root (readlink: Permission denied)
charger_m  116                  root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/116/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
charger_m  116                  root NOFD                                                  /proc/116/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
scsi_eh_0  176                  root  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/176/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
scsi_eh_0  176                  root  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/176/root (readlink: Permission denied)
```

So why am I still getting a listening error? I've allowed port 80 through `ufw` also, so what else do I need to do to try and get this working?

## Edit #1:

I went by [another solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278448/how-to-know-what-program-is-listening-on-a-given-port#278455) on this site to view what was using port 80.

Currently, I'm just running the server off port 8000.

As you can see below, Abyss Web Server is using port 8000, but nothing is using 80. What is going on????

```
user@pc:~$ sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":80"
[sudo] password for user:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       31628      1947/abyssws-x64  
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       31627      1947/abyssws-x64
```

## Edit #2

A comment below suggested I use `ss -ltp` and I was still unable to locate what was using port 80:

```
State  Recv-Q  Send-Q     Local Address:Port             Peer Address:Port
LISTEN 0       80             127.0.0.1:mysql                 0.0.0.0:*      users:(("mysqld",pid=1355,fd=22))
LISTEN 0       50               0.0.0.0:netbios-ssn           0.0.0.0:*      users:(("smbd",pid=2229,fd=34))
LISTEN 0       100              0.0.0.0:pop3                  0.0.0.0:*      users:(("dovecot",pid=2123,fd=24))
LISTEN 0       100              0.0.0.0:imap2                 0.0.0.0:*      users:(("dovecot",pid=2123,fd=38))
LISTEN 0       10          192.168.0.27:domain                0.0.0.0:*      users:(("named",pid=1243,fd=25))
LISTEN 0       10             127.0.0.1:domain                0.0.0.0:*      users:(("named",pid=1243,fd=22))
LISTEN 0       128        127.0.0.53%lo:domain                0.0.0.0:*      users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=817,fd=13))
LISTEN 0       128              0.0.0.0:ssh                   0.0.0.0:*      users:(("sshd",pid=2129,fd=3))
LISTEN 0       5              127.0.0.1:ipp                   0.0.0.0:*      users:(("cupsd",pid=913,fd=7))
LISTEN 0       128            127.0.0.1:postgresql            0.0.0.0:*      users:(("postgres",pid=1241,fd=8))
LISTEN 0       128            127.0.0.1:953                   0.0.0.0:*      users:(("named",pid=1243,fd=23))
LISTEN 0       50               0.0.0.0:microsoft-ds          0.0.0.0:*      users:(("smbd",pid=2229,fd=33))
LISTEN 0       100              0.0.0.0:imaps                 0.0.0.0:*      users:(("dovecot",pid=2123,fd=40))
LISTEN 0       100              0.0.0.0:pop3s                 0.0.0.0:*      users:(("dovecot",pid=2123,fd=26))
LISTEN 0       50                  [::]:netbios-ssn              [::]:*      users:(("smbd",pid=2229,fd=32))
LISTEN 0       100                 [::]:pop3                     [::]:*      users:(("dovecot",pid=2123,fd=25))
LISTEN 0       100                 [::]:imap2                    [::]:*      users:(("dovecot",pid=2123,fd=39))
LISTEN 0       10                  [::]:domain                   [::]:*      users:(("named",pid=1243,fd=21))
LISTEN 0       128                 [::]:ssh                      [::]:*      users:(("sshd",pid=2129,fd=4))
LISTEN 0       5                  [::1]:ipp                      [::]:*      users:(("cupsd",pid=913,fd=6))
LISTEN 0       128                [::1]:postgresql               [::]:*      users:(("postgres",pid=1241,fd=7))
LISTEN 0       128                [::1]:953                      [::]:*      users:(("named",pid=1243,fd=24))
LISTEN 0       50                  [::]:microsoft-ds             [::]:*      users:(("smbd",pid=2229,fd=31))
LISTEN 0       100                 [::]:imaps                    [::]:*      users:(("dovecot",pid=2123,fd=41))
LISTEN 0       100                 [::]:pop3s                    [::]:*      users:(("dovecot",pid=2123,fd=27))
```

### This is getting a bit irritating.

I've also tried `sudo netstat -ltnp`, and every possible command found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/261372/how-do-i-tell-what-is-running-on-which-ports-in-ubuntu) - still showing nothing. What on earth is going on??????

Comment: Ports less than 1024 can be used (opened) only by a root process.  Normally a web server starts with uid=0, starts listening to port (say) 80, and then switches to an unprivileged user (like `www-data`). This may not be the case in your web server. Please check this.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I'm an absolute fool. YOU ARE A KING. I never even though to run it as root! I've been using Linux for less than a week, and that was staring me in the face the whole time. Feel free to put that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP and UDP ports less than 1024 can be used (opened) only by a `root` process. Normally a web server starts with uid=0, starts listening to port (say) 80, and then switches to an unprivileged user (like `www-data` in case of `apache2`).

Your *Abyss Web Server* may or may not be doing this, but in any case, if you want to use a port smaller than 1024, you have to start it from the `root` user.

For more information about "well-known ports" see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports

Comment: This is a standard way of working for any Unix-like and modern Windows system.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli bc otherwise any random user could open the main ports of a system, and is also where most of the default ports are (80, 443, 445, 22...).